# Extract JsonObject inbetween another JsonObject

Tags: android, json

I want to extract the data from JSON data which I have received from an API.
I know how to retrieve simple jsonArray data or a JsonObject from Jsonarray, but I'm new to JSON nesting.

How can I extract this data?

```
{
    "call_log": {
        "7837369400": {
            "7000011216180827872": {
                "start_date": "01 Dec 2014",
                "start_time": "06:08 PM",
                "end_date": "01 Dec 2014",
                "end_time": "06:10 PM",
                "call_sdate": "2014-12-01 18:08:27.000",
                "call_edate": "2014-12-01 18:10:03.000",
                "call_type": "1",
                "caller": "0000000000",
                "duartion": "94",
                "call_duartion": "01:34",
                "dtmf": "NA",
                "dt_number": "0000000000",
                "recording_path": "28.wav",
                "agent_mobile": "0000000000",
                "agent_name": "something"
            },
            "7000301116163015079": {
                "start_date": "30 Nov 2014",
                "start_time": "04:30 PM",
                "end_date": "30 Nov 2014",
                "end_time": "04:31 PM",
                "call_sdate": "2014-11-30 16:30:15.000",
                "call_edate": "2014-11-30 16:31:14.000",
                "call_type": "1",
                "caller": "0000000000",
                "duartion": "59",
                "call_duartion": "00:59",
                "dtmf": "NA",
                "dt_number": "0000000000",
                "recording_path": "30.wav",
                "agent_mobile": "0000000000",
                "agent_name": "something"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code that I'm trying is:

```
try {
    JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("call_log");
    Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() )
    {
        String key = keys.next();
       // __________________________

        // __________________________
        Log.v("**********", "**********");
        Log.v("category key", key);


       // JSONObject jO= new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject(key);
       // Log.v("next is", jO.toString());
       // JSONObject innerJObject = jObject.getJSONObject(key);

       // String name = innerJObject.getString("start_date");
       // String term_id = innerJObject.getString("start_time");

        //Log.v("name = "+name, "term_id = "+term_id);

    }
}
catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read that JSON correctly...

1) Get the call log
2) Get the numbers
3) Get the entries for that number
4) Get values from that entry

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject callLog = responseObject.getJSONObject("call_log"); // 1

Iterator<String> phoneNumbers = callLog.keys(); // 2

while( phoneNumbers.hasNext() ) {
    JSONObject numberLog = callLog.getJSONObject(phoneNumbers.next());
    Iterator<String> callEntries = numberLog.keys(); // 3

    while( callEntries.hasNext() ) {
        JSONObject entry = numberLog.getJSONObject(callEntries.next());

        // 4
        String name = entry.getString("start_date");
```

Comment: okk now i have corrected my question and i have used ur code to get data but getting error in line JSONObject entryObject = numberLog.get(entry); as its says Required org.json.JSONObject but Found java.lang.Object...@cricket_007

Comment: Oops. `getJSONObject`