# Fetch Data from web service and store it in array list

Tags: java, android

Here is the url for a web service:

http://watsmo.com/clients/techmate/getCity.php

It returns JSON data in the following format:

```
{  
   "Andhra Pradesh":{  
      "37":"Anantapur",
      "48":"Bhimavaram",
      "183":"Chittoor",
      "191":"Eluru",
      "52":"Guntur",
      "50":"Kakinada",
      "185":"Karnul",
      "16":"Rajahmundry",
      "182":"Tirupati",
      "17":"Vijaywada",
      "18":"Visakhapatnam",
      "201":"Vizianagram"
   },
   "Bihar":{  
      "88":"Patna"
   },
   "Chhattisgarh":{  
      "163":"Bhillai",
      "164":"Bilaspur",
      "161":"Raipur"
   },
   "Delhi":{  
      "68":"Delhi",
      "61":"New delhi"
   },
   "Gujarat":{  
      "6":"Ahmedabad",
      "173":"Bhavnagar",
      "172":"Jamnagar",
      "136":"Rajkot",
      "170":"Surat",
      "8":"Vadodara"
   }
}
```

This JSON contains names of states and corresponding cities of India.

I want to create an activity with two spinners, first one containing names of the states and the other one containing names of cities corresponding to the state selected in first spinner. It is not possible for me to hard-code this and I am unable to figure out how to do this using the web service. Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: you have to use iterator to get keys, and make `arrayList` of keys

Comment: How but can you please code and give

Comment: what is a problem? do you want somebody to do this task instead of you?

Comment: StackOverflow is not where you get your homework done for you. There are amble tutorials on how to parse JSON into a list and on how to create SpinnerAdapters. I suggest you research both of these topics, try something yourself and come back with specific questions with actual code that YOU wrote

Comment: No i will only do the task but cant get any method to save the states in arraylist

Comment: Can any one tell me how i can save data from web service of state name to arraylist?

Comment: Thanks @rookieDeveloper Done and complete this task

Comment: @HasidMansoori cheers mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable for arrayList

```
 ArrayList<String> keysOfJson=new ArrayList();
```

now after getting your jsonObject do following see if it helps

```
 keysOfJson.clear();
 Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     String key = iterator.next();
     if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
         JSONObject object= jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
         if (!keysOfJson.contains(key)) {
             keysOfJson.add(key);
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: I cant able to get you can you please tell me the full activity of java code

Comment: can you please give me your email address because i cant able to post the code here

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<int,ArrayList<String>> hmData=new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
{

JSONObject jobj1=response.getJsonObject(i)
ArrayList<String> alcities=new ArrayList<>();
for(int j=0;j<jobj2.length()){
 JSONObject jobj2=jobj1.getJsonObject(j);
alcities.add(jobj2.optString(jobj2));
}
hm.put(i,alcities);
//parse the cities from json object and store all cities.

}
```

note: did not execute but this can give you a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can take Help from this similar [question]: [Extract JsonObject inbetween another JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925441/extract-jsonobject-inbetween-another-jsonobject)

Check this one to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might be help for you. to get different City Names and State Name List to set into the Spinner

```
public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

This two method is used to convert your json response into Map Object of two

1. Key(String) : State Name
2. Value(Map): CityId,CityName

**And now you can bifurcate into state Array and City Array(CityId, City Name)**

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        showpDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap =  jsonToMap(response);
                    ArrayList<String> statesName = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<City> finalcityArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
                    HashMap<String,String> mCityHashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    ArrayList<City> cityArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for ( String key : stringObjectMap.keySet() ) {
                        System.out.println( key );
                        statesName.add(key);
                        mCityHashMap = ( HashMap<String,String>) stringObjectMap.get(key);
                        mCityHashMap.keySet().toArray();
                        mCityHashMap.values().toArray();

                        cityArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
                        HashMap<String,String> childCityHashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        for(String cityNumber: mCityHashMap.keySet()){
                           // childCityHashMap = (HashMap<String,String>) mCityHashMap.get(cityNumber);
                            City city = new City();
                            String strname  = mCityHashMap.get(cityNumber);
                            Log.e("TAG","" + strname);
                            city.setId(cityNumber);
                            city.setName(mCityHashMap.get(cityNumber));
                            cityArrayList.add(city);
                        }
                        finalcityArrayList.addAll(cityArrayList);

                    }

                      Log.e("TAG","State Names "+statesName.size());
                Log.e("TAG","City Names"+finalcityArrayList.size());


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        SpinnerApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```